# Soft Delete VS Hard Delete

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, user-experience

I am building a system that will use a commenting based ticket system. I would like to get some opinions around the idea of flagging a user as deleted or removing the record completely.

Ideally I want to keep the system free of old accounts but at the same time by deleting a user the commenting within the ticket system may not make sense.

Has anyone come up with a solution to this type of problem. My ideas so far:

1. Delete the users account, comments and all other relevant data.
2. Flag the user as deleted and create a brand new account if they subscribe again.
3. Flag the user as deleted but if the user was to try to subscribe again update and unflag as deleted instead of adding a new one.
4. Delete the user account only. Then when fetching comments etc. check for an associated id,   if no result found then display the comment with a message "the users account has been deleted".

What do you think?

Comment: Advertising allowed here?  Strikes me as not appropriate.

Comment: -1 : no plugs on other software pls

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I think I will go with option 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the third option is the best choice

My reasoning for this is any tickets stored in the database should be kept for the life of the database, if you attempt to delete a user from the database, you will remove that users reference to any tickets in the database.

(Thats if the database will let you delete it since the user's id will be linked to any tickets he/she may have created)

When that user goes to create a new account in the ticketing system, the tickets that he may have created months ago have dissapeared and may now have been created by null.

Comment: A deleted user should be only able to sign in (activating his account again). If you allow one to signup as a deleted user, you could have problems with stolen identities. But, if you allow deleted users to sign in again, allowing users to delete their accounts is useless...

Comment: yes but your not deleting their account... why force them to sign up again... allow them to use their existing login details

Comment: Exactly! So, what's the difference between deleted/deactived users and active users? They are both able to sign in! That's what I mean.

Comment: deleted refers to gone forever... so therefore soft delete is not actually delete at all its deactivate

Comment: And what's the point of deactivation if I'm not doing anything but setting a flag in the database?

Comment: point being anything related to that user will still have that relation to the user even though the account for that user is not being used anymore

Comment: This system is slightly different. Users cannot sign themselves up or delete themselves. Instead the system has admins that can invite users to participate in projects etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would always use the last solution: delete the user account only and show an "account deleted" message if the poster's account doesn't exist anymore. If you don't allow users to change their username, you can also save the poster's username (beyond his ID) and display it as plain text if the user deleted his/her account, or as a link if the user is still active.

Comment: IMO, your `always` option is the **worst** out of the 4.

Comment: The whole point of a database is to **store** stuff. If you have a user spamming your database and you keep deleting user-accounts it will be very hard to track down who's giving you grief.

Comment: So, you would recommend soft-deleting the account?

Comment: Yep, because that leaves the audit-trail in place, which can a a valuable asset at times, if you're worried about performance, you can always move the user-account data into a parallel table, where it will not slow down your queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you're representing the user <-> comment relationship with a `FOREIGN KEY`, you *can't* delete the user without deleting the comment or updating the comment's associated user to either NULL or to point to some "deleted user" fake user account (in either case, losing the information about the user who posted the comment).

Comment: You can, just add a `on delete set null` or likewise clause.

Comment: That is true, but my point is that you then lose the relationship to the user.  If you are then expecting to remember that relationship if the user account were to reappear, it won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on you use case.
Personally I would never delete stuff like user-accounts from a db completely.

So option 1 is out.    (but that's just me)
Option 2 has the problem, that you'll have lots of dangling user-accounts.
Option 3 looks like the best option  -cough- **audit trail**  -cough-

Option 4 is asking for trouble, you have a link to another table, but that data has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The ticketing system I wrote basically did number 3. Anything else will ruin any audit trails you need to keep.

If you need to get rid of old stuff one way is to set cleardown of old tickets. Then, when all related tickets for an account are gone, you can remove the account.